# How to select vector features with partial (>33%) overlap with another vector feature?

Tags: qgis

I have a grid and a range map, and would like to select those grid squares which overlap at least 33% with the range map.  The range map is a single vector feature.  (I'm new to QGIS but have some Arc experience).

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a handy tool in which you could specify a percent overlap.  However, all is not lost.  One approach could be:

1. create an area attribute in the attribute table for each layer.
2. intersect the two layers
3. select from the new overlap (intersected) polygon layerbased on the the difference between area1 and area2
4. spatial query those polygons from your layer of interest which contain polygons from your selection in the step above.

You can have a few variations on this approach (like doing a spatial join of the area ratio of the intersect polygons back to your layer of interest and then selecting on that value instead of the spatial query).